# How to search a column in a given database table using Entity-framework?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I wanted to provide my site with search feature. How can I search a string in a table?

```
public class SearchController : Controller
{
    HOXATEntities db = new HOXATEntities();
    public ActionResult Index(string search, int? page)
    {
        var pageNumber = page ?? 1;
        ViewData["Posts"] = db.Posts.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 5);
        ViewData["Search"] = search;
        return View();
    }
}
```

The search string is passed and it needs to be compared or whatever from the entity

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
var posts = db.Posts.Where(x => x.nameOfPost == search);
return View(posts.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 5));
```

If you want to search for the name of the post. Otherwise just change it to whatever attribute of post you want to search out. Also you can pop `.ToList()` on the first line above so it becomes:

```
var posts = db.Posts.Where(x => x.nameOfPost == search).ToList()
```

But do notice that all the posts that match the search will be loaded into memory so the list can be populated and be ready for use. If you don't want to load it as a list just used the first example where the returned type will be `IQueryable`.

Then you can alter your view to expect the paged list of posts as the model and then it can render the view based on this.